# Install4J installer icon does not expand to large sizes on Windows

Tags: windows, icons, install4j

I am using Install4J to build a multi-platform installer, and would like to use a custom icon for the installer executable.

I have been attempting to do this by setting the "Executable Icon" property for the Installer in the "Screens & Actions" page. In the "Edit Icon" window, I have added several sizes of icons to the "Cross-Platform Image Files" (specifically sized 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 96x96, 128x128, and 256x256), and chosen "Generate from cross-platform image files" in the Windows section

[image]

When viewing the installer executable in Windows File Explorer this works great when the icon size is set to small or medium in this pane:

[image]

However, when the icon size is set to large or very large, it appears that the 32x32 icon is just shown on a white background. This looks quite silly, especially when the icons for most other programs resize properly.

The effect is similar to how the java icon looks in the following pictures: (I apologize for the annoying highlighting)

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how I could fix this? Or if this is a behavior Im going to be stuck with unless I use a .ico file (which was giving me it's own problems)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indeed a bug in install4j 6.1.5, it will be fixed in install4j 6.1.6. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get the current build where this is already fixed.